# On the parabola y^2=4ax, 3 points E,F,G are taken so that their ordinates are in G.P.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems, parametric

### ***Prove that the tangents at E and G intersect on the ordinate of F.***

This was my approach:

Taking the three points as: E$(at_1^2,2at_1)$  , F$(at_2^2,2at_2)$, G$(at_3^2,2at_3)$
Using the G.P. condition and parametric coordinates, I was able to get:   $t_1.t_3=t_2^2$

Also, as the point of intersection of tangents (genera formula for two points $(t_1),(t_2) $):
$(at_1.t_2,a(t_1+t_2)$ :

---

So, the point of intersection of tangents at E and G had the x-coordinate: $at_2^2$ (as $t_1.t_3 = t_2^2$)

But the question asks us to prove that it will have the same ordinate(y-coordinate) as that of point F...
How can we get that conclusion?

Comment: In fact abscissa of point of intersection of tangents at E and G will be same as abscissa of F,

Comment: Yes! I already got that... What I am asking is, how can I prove that the ordinates is same as that of F as well?

Comment: Ordinates are in AP.

Comment: @ZAhmed I'm not able to understand :(  Can you please give a more detailed explanation?

Comment: $2at_1, a(t_1+t_3), 2at_3$ are in AP.